# Why can't I decode any byte using utf-8?

Tags: python, encoding

Not an expert in encoding, trying to learn.

I got a file in latin encoding, when trying to read it and decode using 'utf-8' I get the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Why can't utf-8 (that uses 1-4 bytes per character) can't decode a latin1 (1 byte per character).

Is latin1 a subset of utf-8? I am pretty lost regarding this so anything helps.

Comment: UTF-8 has certain *rules* that need to be followed for any byte sequence to be valid UTF-8. A standalone `A0` already violates those rules. See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: Unicode is a *superset* of the ISO-8859 character set, but UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding for all of Unicode, while ISO-8859 is a one-byte encoding of just the first 256 code points of Unicode. As such, UTF-8 requires two bytes to encode the non-ASCII characters in that range.

Comment: That is, latin1 is not a subset of utf-8, but the set of *characters* it encodes is a subset of Unicode. The difference between a character set and its byte encoding is something that single-byte encoding schemes tends to blur.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Submit them as a reply so I could give them as valid?

Comment: note: "utf-8" is the format of original bytes, not the destination. Internally Python use an "enhanced Unicode charset" (see it as blackbox, the real encoding is "variable", but unless you are doing C modules for Python, you should not care about it).

Comment: And second note: Python has no idea that original file is Latin1. It could be (for Python, cp1252, cp437, Greek, Cyrillic, complex shift e.g. Japanese, etc.). So you should specify the origin encoding. `0xa0` is invalid in actual context in utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different concepts being confused.

A **character set** is an ordering of characters, numbered from 0 to ...

An **encoding** is a way of representing the numbers in a character set as a sequence of bytes.

---

For a character set with at most 256 characters, a trivial single-byte encoding is possible.

For larger character sets, multi-byte encodings are required. They can be split into two types: fixed size, where every character uses the same number of bytes, and variable size, where different numbers of bytes are used to represent different characters.

Examples of fixed-size encodings are all single-byte encodings and UTF-32.

Examples of variable-sized encodings are UTF-8 and the various UTF-16 encodings.

---

Latin-1 is both a character set (containing the ASCII characters and its additional characters for writing Western European languages) and (having 256 characters) its corresponding single-byte encoding

Unicode is a character set containing (or aiming to contain) all characters to write all known languages. It is, not surprisingly, much larger than 256 characters.

UTF-8 is just one multibyte encoding of Unicode, and a variable sized one. The first byte of each UTF-8 sequence tells you how may *additional* bytes follow it to encode a single Unicode code point.

Unicode and Latin-1 (the character set) coincide for their first 256 code points. That is, Latin-1 is a subset of Unicode.

UTF-8 and Latin-1 coincide for their first 128 sequences. After that, they diverge. In UTF-8, code points 128 through 255 require two bytes. The first byte has the form 110xxxxx, the second 10xxxxxx. The 11 x bits are free for encoding the rest of the Latin-1 subset (plus additional blocks) of Unicode.

The byte `0xa0` is not valid UTF-8, as its binary expansion is 10100000. The first byte of a multibyte UTF-8 sequence always starts with at least *two* 1s (intuitively, the number of 1s indicates the number of bytes in the sequence).